# Negative lookbehind regular expression in R

Tags: r, regex

I have the following vector:

```
vector_3 <- c("oh me oh my", "hello", "oleo", "how ostensible")
```

I want to know which element contains an `e` that isn't preceded by an `h`.

I tried

```
grep("(?<!h).*e", vector_3, perl = T)
```

but this didn't work. The code should return `3`, since the third element is the only element that contains an `e` that isn't preceded by an `h`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `grep("(?<=h).*e", vector_3, perl = T, invert=TRUE)`?

Comment: @nicola: this would also return elements not containing any `e`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep("^[^h]*e", vector_3, perl = TRUE)
#[1] 3
```

Your first problem is that `.*` can include an "h". This can be fixed by a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). If you use that, you don't need the lookbehind.

You also need a start of string anchor. Otherwise every "e" would be a match.

Comment: Cool - thank you. Is there a way to do it using a lookbehind?

Comment: Nevermind - I think I got it: `grep("^[^h]*(?<!h)[^h]*e", vector_3, perl = T)`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use lookbehind here. "Characters except h followed by characters except h that are not preceded by h"?